# How to set Renderable.Primitives to GL_LINES/GL_TRIANGLES in libgdx 3D

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

I m using shader with model batch and I want to debug my model via `GL_LINES`.

```
             /in create();
    Renderable renderable = new Renderable();
    myModelInstance.getRenderable(renderable);
    renderable.primitiveType = GL20.GL_LINES;
    instances.add(myModelInstance);

//in render();
modelBatch.begin(cam);
modelBatch.render(instances, mShader);
modelBatch.end();
```

But it is rendering via it's default primitiveType = `GL_TRIANGLES`

Comment: Try to render the (modified) Renderable instead of the ModelInstance. `renderable.shader = mShader; modelBatch.render(renderable);`. See also: http://blog.xoppa.com/creating-a-shader-with-libgdx/

Comment: @Xoppa it's working from your way, but, how to apply BlendingAttribute. I tried to apply http://pastebin.com/hvRVi8rF